# How do I enable js files compression for Angular CLI 7 application?

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, angular-cli

I'm developing an angular CLI 7 application. After a production build, I have hosted app on IIS. But I cannot see any compression happened in js files when I monitor the requests. Do I need to add any application-level configuration for support compression? Are there any configurations to add in IIS server to support angular compression?

Comment: maybe you want to do gzip for js file ?

Comment: You could use iis static and dynamic compression feature. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/)

Comment: @TonyNgo I have tried using gzip build. But after deploying compression not working.

Comment: I'm using azure and the hosting take care the gzip for me. What is your hosting provider ?

Comment: @TonyNgo I'm using on-premise hosting using IIS server.

Comment: Add answer for you. Try that to see if it work

Comment: IIS has gzip https://support.winhost.com/kb/a1583/enable-gzip-compression-in-iis.aspx

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Thanks, I will try according to the article you given

Answer (score 0):

@bhathiya.m
In your angular.json, you need to add/update the below configurations:

```
 "optimization": true,
 "buildOptimizer": true
```

Do let me know the result.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have these configurations on my app. But after the deployment compression not working

Comment: Angular CLI does not compress JS budles and other assets. They recommend using existing solutions, such as CDN or proxy (e.g. nginx, nodejs) compression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i'm able to help you but this is how I'm using gzip for my web

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-all

And this is the command to run gzip

```
"build": "ng build --prod && gzip-all \"dist/*.*\""
```

Comment: I'm using the same build command. But after deploy app in IIS compress files not used by the IIS. That's the issue.